# How to close an anylogic experiement automatically

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm working on creating a batch simulation process for which I'd like to run a simulation and once it is complete, have it close itself.  I see there are functions for pausing, finishing, and stopping a simulation run, but haven't found one to close the entire program execution.  Does that exist, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest level of control in anylogic is called an experiment.  To close that use `close()`. This will immediately stop the experiment, destroy it and close the windows. [Source](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/Experiment.html)

Experiments may have multiple runs of a simulation.  To stop a simulation you can use `getEngine().finish()` to soft stop it, and `getEngine().stop()` to hard stop it.  [Source](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/simulation-experiment.html#functions)

Comment: The `close()` command may interfere with any file saving at the end of an experiment, causing the windows to just hang there and do nothing.

Comment: thx for sharing with the community, great way to expand the knowledge base :)